# Required type Context provided android.content.Context in android

Tags: android-activity

I am calling a method that takes one argument but when I am passing that argument then it shows an error that the required Type is Context, but provided android.content.Context I don't know that how can I fix that. please help.

Comment: Please post your method, method call details.

Comment: Please add code to understand your question better

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?